# Why does keeping model weights low (with addition of regularization parameter) allow the model to better fit unseen / test data?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

Consider the linear regression model with cost function:

[image: formula]

Here we have [image] = weights of the model

We add the regularization parameter to avoid overfitting the data. The regularization term discourages the use of large weights in favor of smaller weights by penalizing the model according to the weights of the model.
The question is:

1. ***Why*** does keeping model weights low (with addition of regularization parameter) reduce the variance i.e. allow the model to better fit unseen / test data?
2. Also, how does reducing the variance increase the bias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at chapter 7 of Elements of Statistical Learning (online for free here: 
https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf
)
You'll see on page 223 that the expected loss 
E[(w^Tx - y)^2] can be broken down into an 3 parts. An irreducible error term, a squared bias term, and a variance term. As described in chapter 7 there, increasing the number of effective parameters p increases variance and decreases bias. The chapter also describes how increasing regularization strength decreases the effective number of parameters, which is defined to be the trace of the hat matrix.